# robolectric parameterized test - Array of PointF

Tags: android, robolectric, parameterized-unit-test

Good day my fellow developers,

I'm trying to write a Data Driven Unit test for my VectorHelper class. Since the class works heavily on PointF objects and those objects have no implementation in android.jar on host JVM, I use so called shadowing from Robolectric framework. It does work in a simple unit test, however when I try to put PointF objects into parameterized test, it doesn't work and always returns PointF with x=0 and y=0. **Just as it was using stub constructor, without actually setting fields**. Here is my code:

```
import android.graphics.PointF;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * Created by Greg Stein on 9/4/2016.
 */
@RunWith(ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest=Config.NONE)
public class VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest {
    private static final float THRESHOLD = 0.1f;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VectorHelperVerticalAlignmentUnitTest.class.getName());

    public enum AlignmentType {ALIGNMENT_TYPE_VERTICAL, ALIGNMENT_TYPE_HORIZONTAL};
    private static AlignmentType mAlignmentType;

    // Reference vector
    private static final PointF u1 = new PointF(0, 0);
    private static final PointF u2 = new PointF(0, 0);

    // Alignee
    private static final PointF v1 = new PointF(0, 0);
    private static final PointF v2 = new PointF(0, 0);

    public VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest(PointF u1, PointF u2, PointF v1, PointF v2, AlignmentType alignmentType) {
        logger.info("U: (" + u1.x + ", " + u1.y + ") --> (" + u2.x + ", " + u2.y + ")");
        logger.info("V: (" + v1.x + ", " + v1.y + ") --> (" + v2.x + ", " + v2.y + ")");
        this.u1.set(u1);
        this.u2.set(u2);
        this.v1.set(v1);
        this.v2.set(v2);
        this.mAlignmentType = alignmentType;
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        logger.setLevel(Level.FINE);
    }

    @ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner.Parameters
    public static Collection mAlignVectorsTestData() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                {new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(9, 0), new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(9, 1), AlignmentType.ALIGNMENT_TYPE_HORIZONTAL },
                {new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(10, 0), new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(10, -1), AlignmentType.ALIGNMENT_TYPE_HORIZONTAL },
                {new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(-10, 0), new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(-10, 1), AlignmentType.ALIGNMENT_TYPE_HORIZONTAL },
                {new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(-10, 0), new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(-10, -1), AlignmentType.ALIGNMENT_TYPE_HORIZONTAL },

                {new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(0, 10), new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(1, 10), AlignmentType.ALIGNMENT_TYPE_VERTICAL },
                {new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(0, 10), new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(-1, 10), AlignmentType.ALIGNMENT_TYPE_VERTICAL },
                {new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(0, -10), new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(1, -10), AlignmentType.ALIGNMENT_TYPE_VERTICAL },
                {new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(0, -10), new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(-1, -10), AlignmentType.ALIGNMENT_TYPE_VERTICAL },
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void alignVectorSharpAngleTest() {
        VectorHelper.alignVector(u1, u2, v1, v2, THRESHOLD);

        // Test that end vertex has been changed:
        switch (mAlignmentType) {

            case ALIGNMENT_TYPE_VERTICAL:
                assertThat(v2.x, is(v1.x));
                break;
            case ALIGNMENT_TYPE_HORIZONTAL:
                assertThat(v2.y, is(v1.y));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The log output is:

> Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: U: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: V: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: U: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: V: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: U: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: V: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: U: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: V: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: U: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: V: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: U: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: V: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: U: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: V: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: U: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)
>   Sep 04, 2016 4:19:23 PM com.example.neutrino.maze.VectorHelperHorizontalAlignmentUnitTest 
>   INFO: V: (0.0, 0.0) --> (0.0, 0.0)

How to fix it?

Thank you in advance, Greg.

Comment: BTW, changing static initializers for u1/u2/v1/v2 doesn't help.

Comment: Can you confirm that having `PointF` in non-parametrised test is working correctly?

Comment: 2Eugen Martynov: Yes. Absolutely. That is the point in my post. Looks like when I use PointF in parameterized test I use PointF from modified android.jar WITHOUT robolectric shadowing.